# Awk to (random) sample a file by id-uniques criteria

Tags: shell, awk

I'm learning AWK to read a big file which format is similar to this MasterFile:

```
Beth|4.00|0|
Dan|3.75|0|
Kathy|4.00|10|
Mark|5.00|20|
Mary|5.50|22|
Susie|4.25|18|
Jise|5.62|0|
Mark|5.60|23.3|
Mary|8.50|42|
Susie|8.75|8.8|
Jise|3.62|0.8|
Beth|3.21|10|
Dan|8.39|20|
```

I would like to sample by unique values (size K) from the first column with size N (I choose it).

What I have done is following: I select unique values from first column  and save it as IDfile.txt. Later, I take K random values from that archive and I match it with the MasterFile. I mean:

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN{srand()}{print rand() " " $0}' IDfile | sort -n | tail -n K| awk -F'[[:blank:]|]+' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{$1="";sub(/\|/,"")}'1>tmp | awk -F\| 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} {for (i in a) if(index($0,i)) print $0}' tmp MasterFile
```

But the output has repeated values and the result that I'd like to get is like to (assuming that K=3):

```
Beth|4.00|0|
Mark|5.60|23.3|
Mary|5.50|22|
```

I know that my code is far from efficient [or nice] and I'm open to suggestions [].

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the one of the right ways to do this

```
$ sort -t'|' -u -k1,1 file | shuf -n3

Mark|5.00|20|
Kathy|4.00|10|
Jise|5.62|0|
```

change `-n3` to whatever number of unique entries you need.